# Issue with Djangoitem import in scrapy

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I've tried to install `pip install scrapy-djangoitem`, but output is still the same. What is the problem?

items.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem
from article.models import Article

class ArticleItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Article
    author = scrapy.Field()
    dictionary = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
```

Output:

```
(env) taranchik@Dell:~/Public/My Files/IT/work/projects/TEONITE/source/crawling$ scrapy crawl teonite_blog
Files/IT/work/projects/TEONITE/source/crawling/spiders/teonite_spider.py", line 3, in <module>
    from crawling.items import ArticleItem
  File "/home/taranchik/Public/My Files/IT/work/projects/TEONITE/source/crawling/items.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_djangoitem'
```

Comment: Are you added it to installed apps check it once

Comment: still the same.

Comment: Please check if it is properly install or not in your env using pip freeze command.

Comment: I've deleted my .env folder and reinstall the virtual environment and all packages. It does solve my issue. Thanks, everybody for your help.